# Spring Data JPA Query Not Working On MsSQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Please find this bellow query.
This query I written in spring data jpa. So It should be work on all relational database but I get exception on **MsSQL** Server and in **MySQL** it works fine.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.ct,p.ctc,p.fy,"
            + " sum(p.oA + p.nA) as a,p.py "
            + " FROM P p where p.py = :py AND p.fy = :fy "
            + " AND p.B.eId in (SELECT eId FROM B WHERE o.oId in ( :oIds ) ) group by p.ct")
    List<?> test(@Param("py")String py,@Param("fy") Integer fy,@Param("oIds")List<Integer> oIds);
```

This is completely working on **MySQL** server but not working on **MsSQL** server.

While I run in **MsSQL** it gives bellow exception.

```
SqlExceptionHelper: Column 'tbl.ctc' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
[2017-10-27 09:38:38.108] boot - 83734 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ---
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @PM77-1 this is a Spring-data-jpa , so it should work for all relational table.Then why it works for mysql this is my question so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I need this solution on spring-data-jpa , this should be work for both mysql and mssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of Spring Data JPA. You are using a specific feature of MySQL that is not part of SQL standard:

[10.6 General Rules for the GROUP BY Clause](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=6)

> If a select block does have a GROUP BY clause, any column specification specified in the SELECT clause must exclusively occur as a parameter of an aggregated function or in the list of columns given in the GROUP BY clause, or in both.

Your query has

```
SELECT p.ct, p.ctc, p.fy, p.pt
```

with only

```
group by p.ct"
```

generally this is invalid SQL. That's why many other databases (except MySQL) will throw an exception.

Either add columns to `group by` clause or use aggregate function of a column instead.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response. So you mean need to remove group by ?

Comment: Can you tell me what i should change in my above query for solution.

Comment: ok I got it, you mean I need to group by all right?

Comment: The changes may affect the results of your query. So you have to update according to the requirements you have.

Comment: It may be `group by p.costType, p.costTypeCode, p.fiscalYear, p.phaseType`. Or on the contrary `SELECT p.costType, max(p.costTypeCode), min(p.fiscalYear), max(p.phaseType)`

Comment: after adding this I get now this bellow error.
`Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: Share the resulting SQL